# To prolong vs to protract

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What is the difference between the words *to prolong* and *to protract*? Can we replace the words with each other without losing their meanings in the following sentences?

*To protract* means:

> Prolong:
>
> He had certainly taken his time, even protracting the process.
>
> To deprive a successful litigant of interest on his or her legal costs
>   is to encourage the losing side to delay and protract the assessment
>   process.
>
> The ‘winner-take-all electoral vote’ practice can avoid prolonged
>   county by county vote count, which will inevitably protract the
>   delivery of a new president.
>
> We've been in such a hurry for all these years for one main reason -
>   the more the negotiations are protracted, the more difficult they
>   become, which can be easily noticed.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/protract

---

*To prolong* means:

> to make something last a ​longer ​time:
>
> We were having such a good ​time that we ​decided to prolong ​our
>   ​stay by another ​week.
>
> She ​chewed each ​delicious ​mouthful as ​slowly as she could,
>   prolonging the ​pleasure.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prolong

Comment: I think one distinction is *intentionality*. I usually see *protract* in contexts of an *intentional* drawing out to delay some consequence. By contrast, I often see *prolong* in contexts where the delay or drawing out is accidental; a result of inefficient processes, say.

Comment: This extract may help:http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-features/tp-educationplus/what-is-the-difference-between-a-prolonged-meeting-and-a-protracted-one/article897676.ece

Comment: The biggest difference is that _protract_ is not a verb. English borrowed  the participial adjective _protracted_ from Latin to mean _drawn-out_ (literally), but didn't borrow the rest of the verb, so we only have the adjective. You can't say _He protracted the meeting by arguing about every definition_; you could say _prolonged_ or _lengthened_ or a number of other verbs, but not _protracted_. And then there's the fact that the agent noun formed from _protract_ is a tool for geometric measurement -- a _protractor_, involving angles instead of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would possibly suggest that

## prolong

just means, almost literally, **"add length"** or "make longer".

(Note that indeed it can be used, unusually, by - say - designers or engineers in the sense of making some part longer, like a piece of metal or the like.)

"prolong" is somewhat "value free" - it just means "add length".  Whereas

## protract

is sort of a **"bad thing"** (it's somewhat like using - let's say - "spoil" "ruin" "fatten" or the like).  It means stretch out, draw out, pull on, tug on.

(Of course, just to confuse things, I guess in unusual situations you could, indeed, also use "protract" to mean literally draw-out; for example "protract the piece of molten steel an additional 7cm...")

I would be inclined to suggest generally using **protract** at all times in the sense you allude to, as it is **sort of** the "value-laden" word of the two. (It is the "negative" word.)  Leave **prolong** as a value-free word used by engineers/etc to mean "add length unto".

Thus, you're staging *Sound of Music* at high school, you might say "let's prolong it 15 minutes."  You're simply saying, as a "good" thing, let's add in another song and add 15 minutes to the running time. Use protract in cases where something is ("horribly") being drawn-out.

---

Of course ............ we have *"prolong the agony"* as a common phrase - which completely messes up all that I say above!

However it's true that whenever you mean "good" thing (prolong the performance, prolong your experience, prolong the holiday by adding another city, etc) you do indeed use "prolong" as I suggest above.

Answer (score 6):

No, they are not directly synonymous. *Protract* comes from the Latin "to draw out, to pull" (the same root as for tractor). Hence it suggests that the activity has been artificially *stretched*, i.e. lengthened but not overall enlarged. One may wish to *prolong* a pleasurable experience, but not protract it.

Comment: I wanted to add some examples :
When something is extended but you wish not extended it.
Example: I have no desire to protract the process.

When something you want to extend because you desire it.
Example:  We were having such a good time that we decided to prolong our stay by another week.